# Time and Date Picker Dialog in an activity

Tags: c#, android-activity, xamarin

I'm developing a mobile app using Xamarin Studio. And I want to add a Time and Date Picker in an activity. I've tried doing it on a fragment and it works well. But now I want to do it in an activity.

Comment: to add programmatically or what?

Comment: not programmatically.

Comment: ok,check my answer and tell me if ok.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand this

> I've tried doing it on a fragment and it works well

Because its same :)!

OK,check this **out**(via this example you can extract values from Date And Time picker into textview):

Your Main.axml(layout)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TimePicker
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/picker" />
    <Button
        android:text="OK"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnOK" />
    <Button
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnCancel" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:textSize="40dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and your **OnCreate()** method must contains this:

```cs
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

    Button OK = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnOK);
    Button Cancel = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnCancel);
    TimePicker picker = FindViewById<TimePicker>(Resource.Id.picker);
    TextView txt = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txt);

    OK.Click += (sender, e) => 
        {
            //getting values from TImePicker via CurrentHour/CurrentMinutes
            txt.Text = String.Format("{0} : {1}",picker.CurrentHour,picker.CurrentMinute);
        };

}
```

Comment: "I've tried doing it on a fragment and it works well"

What I  mean with this is I've tried the DatePicker and TimePicker Dialog in a fragment and it works well. But I want to do it too in an activity. Is it possible?

Comment: @HunterWinchester yes,try me example. What the problem is?